# NgbCalendar - Angular - Week split bertween two months

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using **NgbCalendar**, the calendar is showing the wrong date according to the day.

On the screenshot we can see the first line has the wrong date (eg. the 1st is a Wed.) and some days are missing on the right.

It seems it is behaving like this for weeks split over two months.

[image: calendar]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: It's looks like your .css about the days not showed has `display:none` or `visibility:collapsed` in stead of a `visibility:hidden`. Really I don't know about ngbCalendar. I know about ngbDatePicker, but I imagine your problem is about a .css

Comment: yes that issues was in .css file, there is already added display: none, the calendar style was overlapped by .css file style that's why they hiding initial three date, I commented display: none in my .css file an it works, thanks for helping me.